# Capitalize first letter and remove space in string

Tags: javascript, regex, spaces, capitalize

Got some code to capitalize the first letter of every word in a string. Can someone please help me update it so it also removes all spaces within the string once the first letters are Capped.

```
return function (str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);
    });
}
```

Comment: [This](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77614/capitalize-the-first-character-of-all-words-even-when-following-a) explains how to capitalize every first letter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var input = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
// \w+ mean at least of one character that build word so it match every
// word and function will be executed for every match
var output = input.replace(/\w+/g, function(txt) {
  // uppercase first letter and add rest unchanged
  return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);
}).replace(/\s/g, '');// remove any spaces

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

You can also use one regex and one replace:

```js
var input = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
// (\w+)(?:\s+|$) mean at least of one character that build word
// followed by any number of spaces `\s+` or end of the string `$`
// capture the word as group and spaces will not create group `?:`
var output = input.replace(/(\w+)(?:\s+|$)/g, function(_, word) {
  // uppercase first letter and add rest unchanged
  return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
});

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Worked a treat many thanks. Decided to accept this as the answer as its a bit more thorough and ideal for other developers looking for this answer :)

Comment: @Richy Okay fine. Enjoy. But I gave exactly the same answer first, before, so if you think in fair, only thing I didn't do is provide a snippet. Right? I will make sure I do that from next.

Comment: That would be good if some explanation is given, specially for regex

Comment: @KaushikThanki added comments

Comment: Doesn't handle preceding white space. Add ".trim()" before the ".replace()" function if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple helper function like:

```
return function (str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);
    }).replace(/\s/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can split the string on the space, capitalize each word and then join them back together again:

```
"pascal case".split(' ').map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1) ).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Page has a nice example of how to capitalize each word in a string in JavaScript: http://alvinalexander.com/javascript/how-to-capitalize-each-word-javascript-string

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordSearch()
{
   var paragraph=document.getElementById("words").value;
   let para2=paragraph.replace(/\s+/g,'');//remove whitespaces
   let para3=para2.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+para2.slice(1); 
   //uppercase first letter
   alert(para3);
 }
```